# How to set up database tables, database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to setup database tables for marketplace website and I'm having some difficulty setting up the tables.

I have about 18 categories, every category has many child categories. So I made a table called `category`, listing the 18 categories with the following columns: `id`, `category_name`, `position`, `visible`.

And I made a table for each category, because every category has different attributes. For example, `real estate` has different attributes than `automobiles`. So I ended up with 18 tables: one table for each category.

1. First question: Am I doing it right creating table for each category?
2. Second question: Every row from every category table represents an ad for an item. I'm confused about how to set up the tables for images. Each ad has a set of images.

   So the question is: Should I create an `images` table for each parent category, or it can be one `images` table for all categories?

Comment: edit it properly so that we can understand

Comment: @PathikVejani on StackOverflow, everyone can edit questions to add more whitespace...

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to StackOverflow, will try to edit it!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you need to read up on how to create relationships between tables, and the concept of foreign key in particular.

Here's my rendition of the schema you described:

```
# Our main table
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  # Regular foreign key 
  `image_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

  # Polymorphic foregin key
  `category_table` enum('automobiles','real_estate') NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

  # Common category data
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `position` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `visible` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  # Foreign key constraints
  UNIQUE KEY `category_table` (`category_table`,`category_id`),
  KEY `image_id` (`image_id`)
);


# A child table that stores automobile specific data
# - `categories` table refers to its records via `category_id` part of the foreign key, when `category_table` equals 'automobiles'
CREATE TABLE `categories_automobiles` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `make` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

# A child table that store automobile specific data
# - `categories` table refers to its records via `category_id` part of the foreign key, when `category_table` equals 'real_estate'
CREATE TABLE `categories_real_estate` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `squarespace` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

# A table that stores images 
# - `categories` table refers to its records via `image_id` foreign key
# - other tables may refer to its record as well 
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  # Either store image data itself in this table
  `image_data` blob NOT NULL,
  # or store file path to the image
  `image_path` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @chromice! i just don't understand why you put foreign keys in the _parent table_, i thought the parent's table _primary key_ must be foreign key in child table, also i thought that we always must set up **constraints** in the child table.

Comment: You could put `category_id` in `images` tables, but then you won't be able to have, say, 'tags' table use `images` table, as each record in `images` table would point to one and only record in `categories` table; and you won't be able to have several `category` records point to the same record in `images` table. As for polymorphic relationship, there's just no other way to define one-to-one relationship. If child tables had `category_id` pointing to main table, you be able to create add a UNIQUE constraint, i.e. each record in `categories` has only one record in *any* child table.